# In Delphi how do I determine when to use Real, Real48, Double or Single data types?

Tags: delphi, types, compatibility

Most of my applications revolve around financial calculations involving payments and interest rate calculations. I'm looking to find out how to determine what Delphi data type is best to use.

If I'm using a database to store these values and I've defined the fields in that database to be a decimal value with two decimal places, which Delphi datatype is most compatible with that scenario?

Should I use a rounding formula in Delphi to format the results to two decimal places before storing the values in the database? If so what is a best practice for doing so?

Comment: Mason is correct with his advice. For what it's worth, Real48 is never appropriate.

Comment: @David: Agreed.  Real48 is an ancient type, kept around for backwards compatibility only, and should never be used in modern code.

Comment: You also forgot `Extended` as floating point and `Currency` as fixed point type.

Comment: With floating point, rounding is a must. Always. `Real48` is for software floating-point (a bit more precise, but times slower than hardware). On significant digits: `Single` appears to be only marginally sufficient, so `Double` (which is essentially the same as `Real`) is ok to use. Study this table: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Simple_Types#Fundamental_Win32_real_types

Comment: @Downvoter etc.: Real48 is not a software FP anymore. It is simply converted to Extended, passed to the FPU and the result converted back.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For such calculations, don't use floating point types like Real, Single or Double. They are not good with decimal values like 0.01 or 1234.995, as they must approximate them.

You can use Currency, a fixed point type, but that is still limited to 4 decimal places.

Try my [Decimal](http://rvelthuis.de/programs/decimals.html) type, which has 28-29 places and has a decimal exponent so it is ideal for such calculations. The only disadvantage is that it is not FPU supported (but written in assembler, nevertheless) so it is not as fast as the built-in types. It is the same as the Decimal type used in .NET (but a little faster) and quite similar to the one used on the Mac.

Comment: are you planning on updating to the new xe2 targets?

Comment: Yes, I am planning on redoing the assembler in x64 assembler. I guess it should make some things a lot easier (larger registers, more registers so perhaps no need to use local vars at all) and some things not (x64 assembler is a little stricter WRT prologue and epilogue code, etc.).

Comment: @Rudy - Thanks for the link. Unfortunately I'm not able to use your Decimal type and here's why. I want to push all the calculations to a stored procedure in a database. I'm finding out that Delhpi, MS Sql Server & ElevateDB all do math slightly differently. If I do the calculations in Delphi and write the results to the database I have several DB I/O's. If I do the calculations inside the stored proc then I need to make sure the calculations are the same as Delphi's. However, I'm accepting your answer because it made me go back to the drawing board and rethink things all the way through.

Answer (score 10):

If you want to do financial calculations, don't use any of the floating-point/real types.  Delphi has a Currency type, which is a fixed-point value with 4 decimal places, that should be just what you need.

Comment: @David Heffernan: Currency doesn't have base 10 but also base 2. Currency is stored as a scaled 64-bit integer with the four least-significant digits implicitly representing decimal places.

Comment: So what data types do I use for this example: 1,000.00 earning 5% interest compounded daily yeilds how much interest? Answer = 0.05/365*(1000) or 0.14. The intermediate calculation 0.05/365 needs to be at least 5 (preferably 7) decimal places. Wouldn't currency truncate 0.05/365 to 0.0001 before it gets used in the rest of the calculation? Or does it keep it's internal value of 0.000136986301... and use that for the rest of the calculation?

Comment: @Cape: Multiplication and division are commutative.  Try 0.05 * 1000 / 365 instead.

Comment: BTW, as with other 80x87 types, `Currency` accumulates computational errors too.

Comment: @David Take a look at the generated asm, and you'll find out that `currency` arithmetic is implemented (at least in 32 bit Delphi) with x87 opcodes. But since it uses the "i" (integer) version of those opcodes, there is no floating-point rounding or error here. But you can safely make currency computation just using the `PInt64(@aCurcr)` pointer typecast (*10000).

Comment: @arnaud that's odd. Why use the floating point unit for integer arithmetic?

Comment: @Arnaud OK, I think I can see why it does this. It's to avoid overflow and it uses the fact that most integers within the valid range for Currency can be represented exactly in IEEE754 data types. Still seems a bit odd to me though.